# nonce versus custom data. is it nonce= or nonce- on the client side? also is it nonce-xyz or 'nonce-xyz' on the client side

Tags: content-security-policy, custom-data-attribute, nonce

I'm confused about nonce implementation for inline scripts and CSS. I defined on the server that the

```
res.locals.cspNonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
```

and

scriptSrc: ["'self'", `'nonce-${res.locals.cspNonce}'`]

and noticed the actual nonce values itself were not showing up on the client browser (Brave) - though none-the-less the script was executing - so not sure if that is just a browser-level security thing because when I changed my client-side inline nonce to something hard-coded like 'abc', the script refused to run which is good. I just don't get it yet. Is "nonce" just a standard phrase? If I so decided could I just set server-side

```
 scriptSrc: ["'self'", `'plackard=${res.locals.cspNonce}'`]
```

so the phrase 'nonce' is really irrelevant and I've just created a rule that client-side all script must match the attribute "`plackard=$somerandomcharaters`"?

Lastly, the server-side settings tend to put single quotes around the 'nonce=something' or nonce-something. Why? I understand the standard HTML 5 syntax for custom data attributes is: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

```
    data-custom="abc"
```

**not**

```
    'data-custom="abc"'
```

The extra single quote seems unnecessary and even would confuse the browser client-side? So put extra single quotes around everything nonce, or ditch them? Is nonce an exception to the standardized HTML5 fieldname="value" paradigm and hence requires single quotes 'fieldname="value"' or not?

If it were my desire would there be any issue with setting my 'nonce' server-side as requiring my script data attribute to say

```
  data-my-custom-safe-attribute="$insertRandomCryptographyHere"
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and noticed the actual nonce values itself were not showing up on the
> client browser (Brave)

Check the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header, your nonce values are there.

> Is "nonce" just a standard phrase? If I so decided could I just set
> server-side  scriptSrc: ["'self'",
> `'plackard=${res.locals.cspNonce}'`]

**nonce** — «number that can only be used once». This name reserved by CSP spec and if you'll use any other names - browsers will ignore 'plackard-base64value' token abd scripts/styles will failed to execute.

> Lastly, the server-side settings tend to put single quotes around the
> 'nonce=something' or nonce-something. Why?

There is not **'OR'**. Single quoted `'nonce-base64value'` is used only in the directives:
  `script-src 'self' 'nonce-ABC' localhost http://example.com data:`
all keyword-expressions (tokens) are single quoted, all host-sources and scheme-sources - are not.

`nonce="ABC"` is used in HTML-tags and it does not single quoted:

```
<script nonce="ABC">
 var inline = 1;
</script>
```

strongly in comply to HTML5 fieldname="value" paradigm.
Pls note that in directive you use 'nonce-**SomeValue**' token and in HTML tags you use nonce=**"SomeValue"** attribute.